# Display Retrieved Image URL in JSON using AJAX Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am retrieving data from the database using Ajax to make the call and the response is in JSON. I can retrieve other data but i need to introduce image, I can retrieve the image URL as can be seen in the JSOn returned but the image is not displaying.

**Below is the Ajax call.**

```
 $("#btnGet").click(function () {
                if ($('#Account_Number').val() == '' || $('#Account_Number').val() == undefined) {
                    alert('Please Enter Customer Account Number');
                    return false;
                }
                $('.spinner').css('display', 'block');  
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                     url: "@Url.Action("AccountDetailsDebit", "Transactions")",
                    //url: "/Transactions/Transactions/SearchAccount",
                    data: '{accountNo: "' + $("#Account_Number").val() + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("Hello: " + response.Firstname + " .\nYour Account Balance is: " + response.Old_Balance);
                        $('#Firstname').val(response.Firstname);
                        $('#Surname').val(response.Surname);
                        $('#Account_Type').val(response.Account_Type);
                        $('#Old_Balance').val(response.Old_Balance);
                        $('#Phone_Number').val(response.Phone_Number);
                        $('#imgPassport').attr('src', response.Image_Url);
                        $('#Account_Number').attr('readonly', 'true');
                         $('.spinner').css('display', 'none');
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                       
                        alert('Account Number Does Not Exist Or Error Processing Request');
                        $('.spinner').css('display', 'none');
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                      
                        alert('Account Number Does Not Exist Or Error Processing Request');
                        $('.spinner').css('display', 'none');
                    }
                });
            });
```

**The JSON response is below:**

```
{"Image_Url":"~/Images/Uploads/SavingsAccount/1000000007.jpg","Account_Number":null,"Firstname":"Sahad","Surname":"HAMMED","Phone_Number":"+46543241324","Account_Type":"Savings Account","Old_Balance":0,"Amount":0,"New_Balance":0}
```

**Below is the View to render the image:**

```
<div class="col-sm-2 w3-card-4">
    <br />
    <h5 class="w3-center"><strong>Mandate</strong></h5>
    <img id="imgPassport"  alt="Upload Image" width="200" height="200" name="imgPassport" />
    
</div>
```

The issue I am having is the image not displaying on the  even though the URL returned exist.

Comment: Whats does console.log(response.Image_Url) output?

Comment: @Crezzur, it is bringing ~/Images/Uploads/SavingsAccount/10000000007.jpg

Comment: that is actually the URL saved and it is retrieving it correctly

Comment: Can you put a break point on $('#imgPassport').attr('src', response.Image_Url); ? It's most likely there is a JavaScript error before it reaches the line. If you get there then examine response.Image_Url. Copy this into a hard coded HTML img (to see if url works)

Comment: @Greg, The response.Image_Url value is "~/Images/Uploads/SavingsAccount/1000000007.jpg". When hardcoded to HTML, it displays the picture perfectly.

Comment: can you inspect the html generated and then click on image src to see if that open in browser or not ?

Comment: @Swati, this is what is been generated  <img alt="Upload Image" width="200" height="200" name="imgPassport"> it seems not to be adding the src to the <img> when the response returns

Comment: Your code seems ok to me maybe problem is some where else .

Comment: It may be the image doesn't load because it starts with ~. Try hard coding different URLs to see what works. Also I would assume you can alter the alt text with  $('#imgPassport').attr('alt', response.Image_Url) (as a way of testing being able to manipulate the html element)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you All for the response. The Response has ~ and that was what was causing the issue. After removing the ~, the image started loading properly